# WPF - Trigger event not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to implement an outer glow effect on a button when pressed. However it seems like my code is not working.

**Error**

> The member 'Style' is not recognized or accessible

**XAML**

```
<menu:HomeButton 
        x:Name="BtnHome" 
        PreviewMouseDown="BtnHome_PreviewMouseDown"
        TouchDown="BtnHome_TouchDown">
        <Button.Style>
          <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DarkBlue"/>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>    
              </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </Button.Style>
```

Note: The HomeButton is a custom class created for an image menu that responds to the button being clicked
Any idea how to fix this?

Edited :
Below is HomeButton class:

```
public partial class HomeButton : UserControl, ILocale, IDisposable
{
    public HomeButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateContentResource();

        this.btnHome.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            KioskSession.BlockEvent(true);
                Debug.WriteLine("Customer click Home button - Return to Home ");

            MainContentSwitcher.Instance.MoveToHome();

        };
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some relevant code about "HomeButton", as it seems it has not inherited `Button`.

Comment: There is no code for HomeButton, that's the only one you can find in the code i posted

Comment: What is `HomeButton`? A custom class? Does it inherit from standard `Button` class?

Comment: If you can appreciate the problem, HomeButton could be anything, we have no idea how this come into existence and cant help

Comment: Yes it is a custom class created for Home button menu.

Comment: if its a custom class, can you at least post the class code?

Comment: Hi. Re your edit to https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18294183, re my rejecting, my take is, no point in "polishing turds". The previous edit by another person was a polish, but no points or reviews were involved. The post should be downvoted & close voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HomeButton` is not a `Button`. Instead of setting `<Button.Style>`, use the following way:

```
<menu:HomeButton 
    x:Name="BtnHome" 
    PreviewMouseDown="BtnHome_PreviewMouseDown"
    TouchDown="BtnHome_TouchDown">
    <menu:HomeButton.Style>
      <Style TargetType="menu:HomeButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
              <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DarkBlue"/>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>    
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </menu:HomeButton.Style>
    ...
</menu:HomeButton>
```

However, note that Since `HomeButton` is not a Button as such, you either have to inherit from standard Button or implement your own IsPressed dependency property, which should be trivial (using MouseDown and MouseUp).

I'd recommend that you simply inherit from `Button` instead of `UserControl`. Looking at the fact that you're applying an effect upon the **pressed** state of the element, it is clear that you want to use it as `Button`.

### Edit

Addressing your confusion, just note that XAML and code-behind of a user control should always match. If your user control says it inherits from `Button`, it should say that in both places. Currently that is not the case with HomeButton class, since it declares itself as `Button` in XAML, and as `UserControl` in the code-behind. To fix the problem, change `HomeButton`'s definition from:

```
public partial class HomeButton : UserControl, ILocale, IDisposable
```

to:

```
public partial class HomeButton : Button, ILocale, IDisposable
```

and everything will start working correctly.

Comment: HomeButton is an image created and also responds to click that brings to another page. That's what it is.

Comment: You made a typo in  </Button.Style>

Comment: @CookieMonster: Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Somehow, it says Property= IsPressed is not recognize or accesible now

Comment: Yep. That's why we were asking about the type of `HomeButton`. Since this is not a `Button` as such, you either have to inherit from standard `Button` or implement your own `IsPressed` dependency property, which should be trivial (using `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`). I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Or I should just opt to implement this effect using Code Behind since it's much direct?? And I don't have to worry about the inherit class as well using codebehind

Comment: If this were up to me, I'd simply inherit from `Button` instead of `Image` unless you need some specific `Image` functionality not available in `Button` class.

Comment: I thought mine is a button class?

Comment: My homebutton.xaml is button class:    <Button x:Name="btnHome" Content="Home" Style="{StaticResource DefaultLanguageButtonStyle}" Width="130" FontWeight="Bold" Background="White" />

Comment: Then you should change `HomeButton`'s code-behind to reflect the same. As of now, your XAML and your code-behind are using two different base classes. I wonder why it is not throwing a compilation error.

Comment: It's so confusing now haha

Comment: It really isn't. If you have defined your HomeButton class in XAML like `<Button ... >`, then you must inherit from `Button` in HomeButton's code-behind too, like this: `public partial class HomeButton : Button, ILocale, IDisposable`. Once you do that, everything will start working correctly.

Comment: I did defined in my HomeButton.cs , is that what you mean?

Comment: Doesn't <menu:homebutton> inherit it as well?

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean now based on your edit. Unfortunately I have other "buttons" as well in my menu so ideally I would not change UserControl.

Comment: Is there any effect changing usercontrol to button?

Comment: No problem in general. You should really change it.

Comment: But the code is an application designed by my colleagues, I would advise not to change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161424/discussion-between-dotnet-and-cookie-monster).

Answer (score 1):

`HomeButton` should be defined as a custom `Buttom` rather than a `UserControl`:

```
public class HomeButton : Button, ILocale, IDisposable
{
    public HomeButton()
    {
        UpdateContentResource();

        this.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            KioskSession.BlockEvent(true);
            Debug.WriteLine("Customer click Home button - Return to Home ");

            MainContentSwitcher.Instance.MoveToHome();

        };
    }
}
```

---

```
<menu:HomeButton 
    x:Name="BtnHome" 
    PreviewMouseDown="BtnHome_PreviewMouseDown"
    TouchDown="BtnHome_TouchDown">
    <menu:HomeButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="menu:HomeButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DarkBlue"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </menu:HomeButton.Style>
</menu:HomeButton>
```

A `UserControl` has no `IsPressed` property so you can't apply your `Style` to a `UserControl`.

Comment: What if I take this approach: Everything in my XAML stays the same as well as UserControl and I just add an event handler to that button, would that work as well?

Comment: Yes, probably. A button is a button and a UserControl is a UserControl.